# Creating automated/self updating calendar date in map window of MapInfo?

Tags: mapinfo, date, 32bit

Id like to know the steps involved in creating (within a map window), a calendar date, in the format dd/mm/yyyy in mapinfo, which updates every day as per the clock on the computer.

I basically want the date to be automated, so I don't have to change it manually every time I create a map.

I am using Mapinfo 12.5, 32 bit.

When answering, If you provide code, can you please point me in the direction of where to put the code, as my knowledge of coding in mapinfo is nil.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Thank you for taking the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Answer (score 1):

Use a variation of the following. An example date looks like: 31 July 2017.
You would have to move the point for map windows in different geographic locations.

Create a table, with:
- one object : a point,
- one attribute named "M" with this value 
1JANUARY2FEBRUARY3MARCH4APRIL5MAY6JUNE7JULY8AUGUST9SEPTEMBER10OCTOBER11NOVEMBER12DECEMBER13

Label the layer with this expression:

```
Left$(Str$(CurDate()), 2)+Chr$(32)+Mid$(m, InStr(1, m, Str$(Month(CurDate())))+Len(Str$(Month(CurDate()))), InStr(1, m, Str$(Month(CurDate())+1))-InStr(1, m, Str$(Month(CurDate())))-Len(Str$(Month(CurDate()))))+Chr$(32)+Right$(Str$(CurDate()), 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to achieve this is to create a table with a single point. Label that point with `CurDate()`. This will label the point with the date format as per your computer settings. So, as long as Windows is set to display the date in DD/MM/YYYY, it will label in the same way.

Then, create a map window with only that point displayed (with no symbology). Add a frame to your layout with that map window.

You'll have to adjust the frame to fit in your layout.  Here's a simple example.

[image]